# create custom durandal modal

Tags: modal-dialog, durandal

I am trying to develop custom modal plugin for durandal 2.1 to have my own logic and abstract it from the rest of my app here is what I have so far but something does not work and modal gets inserted in DOM twice

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'plugins/dialog'], function ($, ko, dialog) {    
var modal = {
    install: function (config) {
        dialog.addContext("Modal", {
            addHost: function (theDialog) {
                var body = $("body");
                $('<div id="Dialog" class="AlignC"><div class="ModalHost"></div></div>').appendTo(body);
                theDialog.host = $('#Dialog').get(0);
            },
            removeHost: function (theDialog) {
                alert("demoving host");
                $("#Dialog").remove();
            },
            compositionComplete: function (child, parent, context) {
                var theDialog = dialog.getDialog(context.model);
            }
        });
    }
};
return modal;
```

});

and here is how i call it from my viewmodel

```
dialog.show(this, null, 'Modal');
```

can anyone tell me what is wrang with this code why my model ELEMENT is inserted twice and ovelay each other. how can i fix that.

second element does not have content inside.

by the way here is view I am trying to show inside modal

```
    <span class="Loader"></span>
    <div class="Modal">
        <h2 class="Caps">SomeName</h2>
        <div class="Row">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="Desc">
            description
            <br />
            XXY YYX XXY
        </div>
        <div class="Buttons">
            <span class="Green">Check</span>
            <span>Add</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to fix this behavior. the problem with click binding was firing twice and this was the problem associated with inserting tow HTML elements in DOM after fixing click handler, everything works just fine.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer to close this question out.